# Is it secure to enable KVM Device for Docker Runner in GitLab Continuous Integration?

Tags: docker, kvm

I need to enable KVM for my [android-ci](https://hub.docker.com/r/kmindi/android-ci/) Docker image to work for emulator based instrumentation tests. The Android emulator requires the kvm device.

Therefore I specify the following in the Runner config (`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`):

```
...
[runners.docker]
...
devices = ["/dev/kvm"]
...
```

Does this somehow impact the security that comes from the isolation between executed Docker images (for a build)?